# Gimp, “Color to Alpha” displays transparency in preview but not commiting change?

Tags: gimp, transparency

I am using GIMP 2.6.11. I have an image I am trying to convert to having a transparent background. I have done this many times. I use the select by color tool, and add layer to alpha channel.

When I select color to alpha from the transparency option, it displays the preview of how it will look. This has the original background converted to the checkerboard background as expected. When I select okay to commit, nothing happens to the actual image on the canvas. What am I doing wrong, because there is not any messages popping up when committing. It just doesn't follow through with the change.

Comment: The current stable version is 2.8.22. But something like this is not known for older versions, either. Can you add a screenshot of the whole ui in this state?

Comment: @MichaelSchumacher   Unfortunately the company I work for limits what we can install to their approved software store. However, closing out Gimp and reopening it seemed to do the trick.

Comment: Next time try `Layer>Transparency>Add alpha channel` before using C2A, especially if you loaded the image from a file type that doesn't support transparency (JPG). Another way to tell if you can have transparency: the layer name should be a normal font, otherwise (no alpha channel) the layer name is in boldface.

Comment: Did you want to write "and add layer to alpha channel" or rather "and add alpha channel to layer"? No offence, but some of my problems get fixed with a good night of sleep and then trying again in the morning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Completely closing Gimp and reopening seemed to resolve this issue.

Comment: So was this a one-off problem, or does it appear often? And does this solution fix it every time?

Comment: Seems to happen intermittently, but closing and reopening does fix it.

Comment: @MartinZaske Happened to me again today, struggling with it, I remembered the solution I posted, and closing and reopening worked. So to properly answer your question, no it's not a fluke, it happens off and on.